# UITest for Android exits when trying to connect to an existing app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to test against an app that has already been installed.
This seems like it should be pretty basic.
But the system just exits.
I have tried with an physical and Android Player device with the same results.  I also tried with different versions of `NUnit` and `UITest` with no luck.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

```java
[SetUp]
public void BeforeEachTest()
{
    app = ConfigureApp
        .Android
        .PreferIdeSettings()
        .InstalledApp("com.xxx.xxx")
        .StartApp();
}
```

```
28-11-2016 23:00:35.310 -05:00 - 151 - Attempting IDE connection for Android: 
/Users/xxx/Projects/AndroidInstalledTest/AndroidInstalledTest/bin/Release/AndroidInstalledTest.dll.
28-11-2016 23:00:35.332 -05:00 - 173 - Attempting IDE connection through pipe 4518cbd3add74221bcd66353094d20a3.
28-11-2016 23:00:35.352 -05:00 - 193 - Skipped IDE integration, connection failed.
28-11-2016 23:00:35.357 -05:00 - 198 - Android test running Xamarin.UITest version: 2.0.2
28-11-2016 23:00:35.394 -05:00 - 235 - Finished with exit code 0 in 31 ms.
List of devices attached
0715f75da7860934        device


28-11-2016 23:00:35.396 -05:00 - 237 - QueryAdbDevices devices output:  [ "0715f75da7860934     device" ]
28-11-2016 23:00:35.398 -05:00 - 238 - QueryAdbDevices found attached devices:  [ "0715f75da7860934" ]
28-11-2016 23:00:35.415 -05:00 - 256 - Initializing Android app on device 0715f75da7860934 with installed app: com.xxx.xxx
28-11-2016 23:00:35.664 -05:00 - 504 - Artifact folder: /var/folders/v3/yqtrsz29495_58109hvl79kc0000gn/T/uitest/a-6708BDC0F5D725725631342F50BE9A748BD7C49C
28-11-2016 23:00:35.664 -05:00 - 505 - Skipping local screenshots. Can be enabled with EnableScreenshots() when configuring app.
28-11-2016 23:00:35.665 -05:00 - 506 - Signing apk with internal keystore.
28-11-2016 23:00:35.666 -05:00 - 507 - Using cached artifact: dev.keystore
28-11-2016 23:00:35.803 -05:00 - 644 - Finished with exit code 0 in 135 ms.
```